# Looking for a single word that describes "up to but not including x" where x is a number

Tags: single-word-requests

Pretty straight forward; I am looking for a word that describes up to, but not including a certain number, if such a word exists.

Comment: Please explain more about the context that calls for this.

Comment: How about when explaining a syntax of a command in a programming language that exhibits this behavior when slicing an indexed array of numbers?  :-P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In most numerical contexts we use "**less than**". That's two words, not one, but it may work for you.

Comment: It's redundant, but this term is sometimes used to diminish the chance of ambiguity or misinterpretation: "less than, not inclusive." (That's four words, while the O.P. requested less than two – but it still might prove helpful.)

Comment: I think 'less than' is sufficient.

Comment: Or "strictly less than".

Comment: @Liz, for the record, I do, too...

Answer (score 5):

**Below** is an obvious one-word answer (I have to write more 'cos it's *below* the minimum length!).

Answer (score 3):

"**Under**", meaning "less than", is only one word. *Under X.*

Answer (score 2):

For the numbers coming before but not including, I think you could say:

*preceding* X.

[preceding:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/preceding) Existing or coming before another or others in time, place, rank